# How do I capture the backspace key in IE8 with jquery?

Tags: jquery, keydown, backspace

I've got a simple javascript keydown event coded via jquery. The event should just alert the key that is "down." This works for most keys but not the backspace key in Internet Explorer. I read that IE messes this up on the keypress event but was supposed to work for the keydown and keyup events.

Is there anything I can do via jquery to capture the backspace in IE? The version of IE I'm currently testing in is:

8.0.7600.16385

```
        $('.AddressField').bind("keydown", function (e) {
            alert(e.keyCode);
        });
```

Comment: I am unable to duplicate this behavior on [the demo page for event.which](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) using IE8 8.0.7600.16385 on Windows 7 64-bit.  Maybe it's a problem with keyCode?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use which:

```
  $('.AddressField').keypress(function(e){
       alert(e.which);
   });
```

Comment: Why does IE make things so difficult :-(  Thanks, this worked great. I'm checking keyCode and which at this point just to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

`keyCode` property is not available in IE. In IE you must use `which` property.