# Internet Explorer key down event messing up

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, events, firefox

so I have this code:

```
$('.textarea').bind('keydown', function(){
  alert('yooooo');
});
```

now suppose I enter a bunch of chracters into textarea, then press Ctrl+A (or select all) and then press backspace, in Firefox the 'yoooo' will be alerted properly following the backspace, but not in Internet Explorer...

is there a way to make this also work in IE for that action (select all then backspace)...is there some other event that I need to use?

Comment: What is not working?  I tested in IE8 and saw the alert on every keypress.

Comment: maybe you aren't loading the jquery library properly? should be working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3305480/how-do-i-capture-the-backspace-key-in-ie8-with-jquery

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Works for me in IE9...
http://jsfiddle.net/BarAB/

It's annoying as all hell, but it does what you want it to in IE as well.

Comment: Oh really? view this in IE and then in chrome and tell me why it looks different? http://jsfiddle.net/jHXkF/

Comment: oh okay you are right, I ran navigator.userAgent in all the windows.